# rspec assigns for session fails

Tags: rspec

My test fails and says on test report

> Failure/Error: assigns(:items).should eq(item) expected: [# Item id:
>   756, product_name: "Item 1", product_price: 310.25, product_balance:
>   3, active: 1, created_at: "2012-10-11 20:10:23", updated_at:
>   "2012-10-11 20:10:23"]
>               got: []

Can you please tell me what is wrong why the test fails?

cart_controller.rb file

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cart = session[:cart] || {}

    @items = Item.where( id: @cart.keys )

    @cart_cost = 0
    @items.each do | item |
      @cart_cost += @cart[ item.id.to_s ]*item.product_price
    end
  end
end
```

cart_controller_spec.rb

```
describe CartController do
  context "when user is logged in" do

    before (:each) do
      v = Visitor.create! :username => 'John Doe', :password => '123456'
      session[:logged_in] = 'logged_in'

      session[:cart] = {}
      @cart = session[:cart]

      @normal_item = Item.create! :product_name => 'Item 1',
:product_price => '310.25', :product_balance => '3', :active => '1'
    end

    describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "assigns session cart variable as @cart" do
        get :index
        @cart[ @normal_item.id ] = 1

        assigns(:cart).should eq(session[:cart])

        item = Item.where( id: @cart.keys )
        assigns(:items).should eq(item)
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the session values as the second argument to `:get`, e.g.:

```
get :index, {}, { :cart => {}, :logged_in => 'logged_in' }
```

This is described in more detail in [A Guide To Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers)